Error with header and footer after \AtBeginDocument using custom document class
I am working on a conference paper and need to use a custom document class (see below)
I cannot get the header and footer definitions after the first page to work.  I am simply trying to add "Approved for Public Release" in the header and footer on pages after the title page. I've tried defining them before the \AtBeginDocument statement I've tried afterwards and it just keeps showing blank with no headers or footers. I've also tried removing the \fancyhf{} line but that also doesn't work.  I don't want to change the format on the first page header either.  I've tried searching for a solution and looked extensively at the overleaf documentation but I haven't found a solution that works from me yet.  I've wondered about sizing effecting the display but I don't see how the size would play into this since its just text and page numbers I'm trying to add.
Class file for the paper of the 1st joint International Conference on Multibody 
System Dynamics
%% MKM 20012010
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{msd2014_fullpaper}[2014/11/14 IMSD paper class]
\ProcessOptions\relax

\DeclareOption{10pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % for unix users
\RequirePackage[ansinew]{inputenc}  %  for windows users
%\RequirePackage[aplemac]{inputenc}  % for mac users

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{times}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsbsy,amsmath}
\RequirePackage{latexsym}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{a4}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{engord}
\RequirePackage{epsfig,vmargin,booktabs}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage[all]{hypcap}
\RequirePackage{url}

\setpapersize{A4}  % needs vmargin package
%\setmarginsrb{left}{top}{right}{bottom}{headh1gt}{headsep}{foothgt}{footskip}
\setmarginsrb{30mm}{5mm}{30mm}{5mm}{25mm}{0mm}{0mm}{25mm}
% headsep:  Distance from bottom of header to the body of text on a page.
% foorskip: Distance from bottom of body to the bottom of the footer (the footer is the text at the bottom of each page).


\parindent=0pt
%\parskip0pc
\parskip=2ex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
 }
 \urlstyle{same}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 ....table, figure, section definitions

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \AtBeginDocument{%
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyfoot[C]{Approved for Public Release}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \rhead{
       \scriptsize{
          The {\engordnumber{7}} International Conference on Multibody System Dynamics
       }\\
       June 9-13, 2023, Madison, WI, USA\vspace{5mm}
    }
 }


Perhaps you should start by explaining what the end goal is. Then we don't have to spend a lot of time trying to figure out what exactly your code is suppose to do.

Just a note: There is nonsense in the class, e.g., loading package a4 but afterwards using package vmargin to setup page size and margins. And because you are using tag [tag:overleaf] I guess, that you are using Overleaf. In this case you should note, that Overleaf encodes the input UTF8, so \RequirePackage[ansinew]{inputenc} would be wrong. (BTW: The comments after all the inputenc lines are wrong for a very long time and IMHO already 2014).

This document class was not written by me, I am simply required to use it, it is what the conference has issued to their authors.  I'm trying to tweak the headers and footers to add "Approved for Public Release" on each page after the first page.  That is all.

You probably need something like
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
 \fancyfoot[C]{Approved for Public Release}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \rhead{
    \scriptsize{
       The {\engordnumber{7}} International Conference on Multibody System Dynamics
    }\\
    June 9-13, 2023, Madison, WI, USA\vspace{5mm}
 }
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \AtBeginDocument{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
 }

(and maybe 2023 should be 2024).
